# Why can't I use 'use' in an async block, in F#

Tags: f#

I have this function to read data from a cache:

```
let private tryLoadFromCacheAsync filename =
    async {
        let filespec = makePath filename
        match File.Exists filespec with
        | true  ->
            let! bytes = File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filespec) |> Async.AwaitTask
            use pBytes = fixed bytes
            let sourceSpan = Span<byte>(NativePtr.toVoidPtr pBytes, bytes.Length)
            return Some (MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ShortTradeData>(sourceSpan).ToArray())
        | false ->
            return None
    }
```

the line of interest is here:

> use pBytes = fixed bytes

it will fail to compile with:

> The type 'nativeptr<'a>' is not compatible with the type 'IDisposable'

but the line will compile as:

> let pBytes = fixed bytes

and this is happening in an **async** block.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is less about the `use` part and more about the `fixed` part. The fixed keyword ensures that a value is kept on stack. The issue with combining this with `async` is that local variables used in computation expressions are not always kept on stack. If you have `let!` in between their uses, they need to be stored as fields of an object, so `fixed` cannot work in such context.

You could fix this by limiting the scope of the fixed variable to a non-async code block:

```
let private tryLoadFromCacheAsync filename =
    async {
        let filespec = makePath filename
        match File.Exists filespec with
        | true  ->
            let! bytes = File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filespec) |> Async.AwaitTask
            let res = 
                use pBytes = fixed bytes
                let sourceSpan = Span<byte>(NativePtr.toVoidPtr pBytes, bytes.Length) 
                MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ShortTradeData>(sourceSpan).ToArray()
            return Some res 
        | false ->
            return None
    }
```